# Complete specific task in ThreadpoolExecutor in python then loop it over?

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, signal-processing, threadpoolexecutor

I have been working to develop an algorithm in python in which certain tasks need to be computed in parallel. I am using threadpoolexecutor to do it. My specific section of code is:

```
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=number_of_threads) as executor:
    for chunk in NearEndChunks:
        test = ED.EchoDetection()
        futures = {executor.submit(test.echoDetection, chunk, FarEndChunks, i, i + chunk_shift): i for i in
                   range(zero_ms, delay_line_max, chunk_shift)}
  
        if ED.EchoDetection.FOUND.value == 1:
            print(
                f'Echo detected and indexes are as : near end index = {test.NEARINDEX.value} and  '
                f'Farend '
                f'index = {test.FARINDEX.value}')
            break
```

The problem I am facing :

This function **test.echoDetection** doesn't return anything so futures have nothing to do with this code.
Problem is that when I run this code, it creates multiple threads as mentioned in variable **number_of_threads** which is 15 in my case for now but it doesn't compute all the tasks and then new threads are being created and it goes on and on till I get following error:

> Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)

Solution I want:

How do I make it work that it completes all the tasks and then new loop runs? In java there is **ThreadPoolExecutor#getActiveCount()**. What's the alternative for it in python. Also, is there any other better approach to perform these calculations?

Regards,
Khubaib